# Springboot logging level disable DEBUG logging on Gitlab

Tags: spring-boot, java.util.logging

On our bootstrap.yml of our test units

```
logging:
  level:
     com.xxxx: INFO #from DEBUG
```

However the debugging still shows on Gitlab but it the INFO logging works when i run it local
Why is Gitlab still show DEBUG level logging?

Note that these are flowable debug logs and i have tried logging.level.org.fowable = info but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use logback-test.xml and place in within resource folder of each module

```
<configuration>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO"/>
    ##additional entries
</configuration>
```